# repeat a multi job in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I used `jenkins' Multijob plugin` and run a test that contain 4 tests in it. Now I want to repeat this test for many times (for example 10 times), but some files are different in them.

Is that any way to config multi jobs to ran some jobs with other config files?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "other config files"? Do you mean files that changed in your version control? Or do you mean files that you want to give your jenkins-jobs as a sort of parameter?
In the latter case you could simply make your builds "parameterized" in jenkins and define the parameters (you can then use the parameters in your build steps).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Actually I have a program that when it starts it used from a file. Now I want to repeat this job for 10 times and used the proper file.(This file is different in each jobs.)